# How can I alter these wooden towel hooks so that the towels don't fall off?

Tags: bathroom, paint

We have this rack of towel hooks in our bathroom, but the hooks are so smooth that the towels easily fall off.

[image]

How can I alter it so that the towels don't fall off?

I'd rather not roughen up the wood, as it may pull thread out of the towels. Perhaps there's some sort of rubbery coating I could paint on to the top of each hook?

Comment: Sugru, if you have it. Black tape maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a product called Plasti-Dip that used to be carried at Harbor Frieght along with most hardware stores. I was a liquid vinyl used for coating tool handles. It dries to a soft grippy texture and comes in colors.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I used some white silicone sealant that I already happened to have. Seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Find more twine or rope (looks like a natural sisal) that matches the "laces" on the shoes. Wrap the twine around the posts in a spiral until they are completely covered. You will probably need to glue the twine occasionally, and perhaps rough up the paint so the glue sticks.

The twine in the picture looks like it is waxed. I would make sure to use non-waxed if you are going to wrap the posts, otherwise the towels would still probably slip right off.

Answer (score 5):

Cheap fix: Get a heavy, wide rubber band and wrap it around the middle of the ball. The wider the better, to prevent it rolling off.

Caveats: Rubber bands decay over years, and if you leave it on until it breaks you may find some rubber stuck to the surface. This could also trap water, allowing mold growth. I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

A dab of Sugru, rubber compound you can buy on internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can get towels to stay on even very smooth knobs.  Drape the towel over the knob and then twist the ends half a turn.

Or, repaint the hanger using a satin (non-gloss) white paint.

Or, loosen the screws and shim the bottom of it to make the knobs point at a slight upward angle.

Comment: I like that last idea!

Answer (score 0):

300 grit sandpaper will remove the polish from those knobs.
If you're even moderately careful of how hard you rub, it won't wreck the paint either.